# How to get caret position in RichTextBox which contains rtf

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I am making a "reading speed tester" application using `RichTextBox`.

I need to colorize text fragments by moving caret in next position. So, when I load plain text file in `RichTextBox` - I can get proper caret position using `rtb.CaretPosition`.

But when i load `rtf`, `CaretPosition property` returns me '60' for first character. So it's correct, but I want to get caret position in text without any formatting (special symbols).

Can i do that without parsing rtf and converting one caret position to another manually ?

Comment: `1. I need to colorize text fragments`, `2. But I want to get caret position in text without any formatting` these are two diff things. point 1 has nothing to do with point 2. Do you want same caretposition values like you get with text content ?

Comment: I have function colorizeText(startIndex,endIndex); So, when i use plain text without formatting rtb.CaretPosition allows me to get correct caret position. But when i set Rtf property of richTextBox rtb.CaretPosition returns incorrect indexes; Forget colorizing, it doesn't matter. Main question is how to get caret position in RichTextBox, which contains RTF.

Comment: You are already getting caretposition.

Comment: yes, i get some value, but it's not correct, because it must return 0 for first character, but it return 60. So, how to get correct value ?